# wpf datagrid. Highlight rows, which have omitted data between them

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers

I have a datagrid filled with data, one of the columns stores item's id. If there are rows, which have omits in id, i need to highlight them, for example: row1 has id=40, row2 has id=42, id=41 is missind. Can i somehow implement this using datatriggers or something like that?

Comment: Why not the easiest approach? Loop through the items, compare the next item's ID against the current one, if not as expected: do something.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva because it looks ugly in mvvm for me and i think that datatriggers would work faster, don't they?

Comment: You could always check the last item when a new one is added, if an id is missing, set a property and have a style trigger highlight the item.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva Well, i don't add items, i re-load data every period of time... So i don't know how my VM and even Model can be separated from View in this scenario

Comment: Then I don't think there is any way other than looping through all the items...

Comment: @RodrigoSilva okay, but when? cannot find correct event...

Comment: Well, you said "I reload data every period of time". So loop through it everytime you reload it.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva is there any proper event? OnsourceUpdated and DataContextChanged are not what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodrigo Silva's suggestion is good so do that if you can. If you can't/don't want to - here is one way that you can do it with a DataTrigger:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <app:MissingRowCheckConverter x:Key="MissingRowCheckConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MissingRowCheckConverter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Item" />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" Path="ItemsSource" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyData> list { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (i == 3)
                    continue;
                MyData d = new MyData() { id = i, name = "Name " + i.ToString() };
                list.Add(d);
            }
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MissingRowCheckConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        #region IMultiValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length > 1)
            {
                MyData d = values[0] as MyData;
                if (d == null)
                    return false;

                ObservableCollection<MyData> list = values[1] as ObservableCollection<MyData>;
                if (list != null)
                {
                    // Check if any in the list have id - 1
                    if (list.Any(aa => aa.id == (d.id - 1)))
                        return false;
                    // Check if this is the lowest id
                    if (!list.Any(aa => aa.id < d.id))
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you much! That's the one i was searching for!

Comment: Well, your approach has one trouble, when grid uses virtualization, the rows get background wwrong, they duplicate based on first shown page. That means that if on first page row number one must be highlighted and there are 20 rows on screen, the 21st row will also be highlighted... How can i deal with this trouble? For now i have turned row virtualization off and your code works great, but a little bit long

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy - I made changes to the answer. Instead of binding to the DataGridRow, I bind to the DataGridRow's item. I also changed it to add 99 items to the grid so I could test the error and the fix.